# VBA check to see if 2 cells are the same, if they are then SUM 2 other cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to SUM 2 (or more) values together in VBA, but to find out which cells to SUM i need to check if cells in another column are the same.

EXAMPLE

- VVVAAA - 14 - 14 -
- VVVAAA - 13 - 27 -
- VVVBBB - 10 - 10 -
- VVVBBB - 12 - 22 -

Basically if cells in column A is the same then SUM all values the rows in column B that match and put the answer in column C

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more specific advice. Thanks!

Comment: do you wan the ouput you are showing, a running total?

Comment: You do not need vba, a simple formula will do it.

Comment: @ScottCraner yes I want an extra column made for a running total of all the values in rows that have VVVAAA and then a separate running total for rows that have VVVBBB.  How could i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for VBA use SUMIF with a dynamic Range:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:A2,A2,$B$1:B2)
```

Pay attention to the fact that the first cell in the ranges are absolute while the second is relative allowing it to move down as the formula is dragged down.

[image]